# Start app and navigate to the view previously displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, suspend

I have an app (iOS, Swift) which is usually started in the morning by the user. The user will press a couple of buttons, enter some text, move to other views (using a navigation controller) and so on. When everything is filled out the right way, the user will put the iPhone into standby mode. As far as the app life cycle is concerned, it will enter the background state. When the user opens the app again, he will still be on the same page, with the same parameter, ... Everything is fine.

In case of a suspended app (due to a lack of resources or other stuff), the app will start again from the beginning and not from the view where the user has navigated to before. In such a case, what's the best way to navigate to the specific view the user was when bringing the phone into the standby mode and keep respectively build up the whole navigation stack as it was before the suspension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apple state restoration and preservation technique for this purpose. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StateRestore/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013190-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) you can find an example provided by Apple.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Seems like I have to code a bit by my own in addition to the default state preservation and restoration.